# facebook album upload

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

While uploading a photo to facebook using graph api, will I come to know the source/location where the image is saved ? For example, source like this : http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_n.jpg

I need to save this location into the database, so that other users can view this.

If it is not possible, can I get the location using FQL query from album after uploading the photos into facebook ? may be something like, "SELECT aid, owner, location, link, object_id FROM album WHERE aid="20531316728_324257" and save the link or location to the database. well this may not be the right query.

Or are there better ways ?
requirement is, user-A should upload photos into facebook from my website and user-B (or everybody) without login to facebook should be able to see these photos what "A" uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a photo via the graph api the return result is the image graph id.  You can the query the graph using that id like http://graph.facebook.com/{returnedId} and that will give you all the different urls for the different image dimensions FB creates after the upload.

an example: `http://graph.facebook.com/10150178799547321`

Comment: The image is uploaded and I got a returned id also... but when I used http://graph.facebook.com/{returnedId}, it returned with an error code, {
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}

Comment: can you post the id that was returned from the upload so I can follow up?  I don't think you need a token but you can always try https://graph.facebook.com/{theId}?access_token={yourAccessToken} Which should return what your looking for as well. The comment is stripping out my / from the url be sure to include and make sure you're using https.